# How to format this string to a Date

Tags: php, date, time

I have some strings that will be different dates and times. Each one will be different and I'm looking to format them to my liking.

For Example:

> 2016-04-15 14:20:00

I would like to be able to take this string and use PHP's Date function to format it to my liking.

For Example:

> 04/15 2:20pm

So would I take the string and convert it to a timestamp first? If so how do I go about doing that?

Comment: Please have look at http://php.net/manual/en/datetime.format.php

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try this ..

```
<?php

    $time = strtotime('2016-04-15 14:20:00');
    echo date('m/d g:ia', $time);

?>
```

**Second Way**

```
<?php

$format = 'Y-m-d H:i:s';
$date = DateTime::createFromFormat($format, '2016-04-15 14:20:00');
echo  $date->format('m/d g:ia');

?>
```

Comment: Thanks for the help =). The first way worked perfectly.

Answer (score 2):

You can return a new DateTime object formatted according to the specified format by using [this](http://php.net/manual/en/datetime.createfromformat.php) function. Then you can format it [as you like](http://php.net/manual/en/datetime.createfromformat.php#refsect1-datetime.createfromformat-parameters).

```
<?php

$testDate = '15-Feb-2009 11:00:34';

$date = DateTime::createFromFormat('j-M-Y H:i:s', $testDate);
echo $date->format('Y-m-d');

?>
```